# Swift - Updating entries in core data

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode7

**Context:**

A game, at the end of the game the user retrieves a score. A function is called to save the score to the DB

**Logic:**

1. Query the DB to check if a record exists
2. If a record exists, retrieve the score, if the current game score is higher then the score retrieved then update the record
3. If you are  new user then make a new entry into DB

**Issues**

It keeps saving new entries to the DB and not updating the 1st entry. I only want the user to have the 1 entry that gets updated as they keep getting higher scores.

Is there anywhere I can see the localDB to see what's going on?

Also this seems verbose, is there an easier way?

**Code**

```
    func saveName(score: Int, whereToStore: String) {
        //1
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest   = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Scores")


        //2
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Scores",
            inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        let yourScore = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)



        /*Fetch results */
        do
        {
            let fetchedResult = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]

            if let results = fetchedResult
            {

                if results.count > 1{
                    //Do some update code here if existing record in DB
                    print("Code to update number one result")
                    //yourScore.setValue(score, forKey: whereToStore)

                    let updateScore = results[0].valueForKey(whereToStore) as! Int

                    let updateScoreObject = results[0]

                    print("Score got back is \(updateScore)")


                    if (score > updateScore){

                        print("time to update")

                        updateScoreObject.setValue(score, forKey: whereToStore)


                        do {
                            try updateScoreObject.managedObjectContext!.save()
                            print("updated \(updateScoreObject)")
                        } catch {
                            let saveError = error as NSError
                            print(saveError)
                        }

                    }



                } else {
                // Do the saving here if you are a new user

                    //3
                    yourScore.setValue(score, forKey: whereToStore)


                    print("DOES THIS CODE RUN")
                    print("your score is\(yourScore)")



                    //4
                    do {
                        try managedContext.save()
                        //5
                        print("worked, I saved")
                    } catch let error as NSError  {
                        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }


                }


            }
            else
            {
                print("Could not fetch result")
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("There is some error.")
        }



               }
```

**Update**

Added

```
let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

print("\(documentsUrl)")
```

So I can find the local SQLite and opened up with a DB viewer, as expected it keeps saving new entries rather than updating the 1st

Comment: Why do you need "insertIntoManagedObjectContext" ?

Comment: You are adding entry yourScore before you do the fetch.

Comment: Changed the order slightly as Willeke suggested, reset simulator and seem's to be working now. Still feels a little verbose, will do some learning on core data as certain I can do this better